# Pandas: Expand column string values based on matches in a list of longer strings

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Can anybody think of a neat way in pandas to expand a column with file names of images to a column with full URLs based on a list with URLs?

I have following dataframe

df1:

```
"src"  "obs1"  "obs2"   
myimg_1  val_11  va1_12
myimg_2  val_11  val_22
```

And the following list

list1:

```
https://path/to/myimg1
https://path/to/myimg2
.
.
https://path/to/myimgN
```

What I need is the following dataframe:

df2:

```
"src"  "obs1"  "obs2"
https://path/to/myimg1 val_11  val12
https://path/to/myimg2 val_21  val22
```

The same image file name of df1['src'] could potentially be in multiple URLs in list1, but lets assume that is not the case. Otherwise I would just need a single URL and not all possible matches in list1.

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Comment: does there exist a mapping between `myimg_1` and `https://path/to/myimg1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dataframe from your list and extract the last part of url with `urlparse` and `os.path.basename`. Finally, use `merge` to add column `url` to your original dataframe.

```
>>> df
      src    obs1    obs2
0  myimg1  val_11  va1_12
1  myimg2  val_11  val_22

>>> urls
['https://path/to/myimg1', 'https://path/to/myimg2', 'https://path/to/myimgN']
```

```
# from urllib.parse import urlparse
# import os.path

df1 = pd.DataFrame(urls, columns=['url'])
# df1['src'] = df1['url'].apply(lambda x: os.path.basename(urlparse(x).path))
df1['src'] = df1['url'].str.split('/').str[-1]

df = df.merge(df1, on='src')
```

```
>>> df
      src    obs1    obs2                     url
0  myimg1  val_11  va1_12  https://path/to/myimg1
1  myimg2  val_11  val_22  https://path/to/myimg2
```

*Note: I slightly modified your dataframe because `myimg_1` has no match to your list. Typo ?*

Comment: Very neat, thanks a lot. Worked perfectly and readable too. To minimize imports I would have preferred to use the build in split in the lambda function, i.e.  "x.rsplit('/',1)[-1]" rather than "os.path.basename(urlparse(x).path)". For some reason that doesn't work, if you know why please tell. For now I will stick with your suggestion. Thanks again! 

Oh and yes the myimg_1 was a typo!

Comment: I updated my answer to minimize imports. ty for your vote.